# How can I do video capture in the browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, webcam, html5-video

Ideally what I was initially looking for is an implementation of the HTML5 Media Capture API with a polyfill rolling back to Flash, however, my research has concluded that the API is in its infancy and is yet to be taken up by any of the major vendors, and in addition to that, Flash means for doing what I need seem scarce.

I need to be able to take webcam input from a camera, show a live preview, record, and play back that recording, nothing more, no upload to server necessary, all local.

Are there any decent Flash solutions? Or other means of achieving this?

I have found a lot of references to Red5, to clarify, would that refer to this: http://www.red5-recorder.com? Is this really the tool to use or are there better alternatives?

Comment: It seems Red5 does recording on the server-side, so it isn't suitable :(

Comment: Actually what happens is the audio and video data is captured by the Flash client running in the browser, encoded (by Flash player/the computer running the client) and sent via streaming/rtmp to the media server (Red5). The media server's job is just to put that data into .flv or .f4v or mp4 files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using http://nimbb.com for this, the free version has some limitations but gives the basic functionality needed met my criteria for the project.

In addition to my needs it also allows users to upload recordings to the Nimbb website and share over social, which can't hurt!

Comment: If you're looking into your options now, device capture support is now much better, at the very least iOS6 supports and I believe some if not all of the major desktop browsers do too, so depending on your project's needs you may now be able to get around this without using Flash (or perhaps only as a fallback).

Comment: You might also try http://hdfvr.com as an alternative to Nimbb. It uses a Flash client on the desktop and HTML Media Capture on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

I too am looking around for the same feature.  The best I found was Open-Tok, they do all the work

http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/plugnplay#VideoMessages

My problem is my site is adult in nature, so the people recording the videos would more than likely be naked. This is against the terms of service for Open-Tok  I do like their offering.